# "be evil to V" vs. "it is evil to V"

Tags: difference

Are the following sentences more or less interchangeable?

> a. It was evil of John to adopt a baby for his experiment.

> b. John was evil to adopt a baby for his experiment.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first states that the act of adoption was evil.

The second states that the person of John was evil.

It is a matter of opinion whether a good person can commit evil acts.